# Create a folder structure using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: git, github, libgit2sharp

The idea is this.  We are running an internal "GitLab" with a bunch of repositories.  Some of these repositories are used by UX people that they would like to have synced with a website used to show clients their work.  They asked me to make an interface where uses could enter the url of their repository and I would sync it to the website.

I have created a scheduled task that will read the website for repositories entered then using "LibGit2Sharp" get the files locally.  Then those files will be transferred to the website using FTP.

Is the design perfect?  No, but I am still learning and this is just an internal project before I land at another client.

In affect I would like to get the repository, and put each branch into its own folder.  I have successfully gotten the repository and pulled the latest.  And I have also done a checkout to switch branches, but then the pull didn't work and it still doesn't accomplish my file structure.  Is there an easy way to do this, or am I going to have to create a new repository for each branch and do a checkout there?

**TL;DR  Is there a simple way to get a Repository and its Branches as Folders using LibGit2Sharp?**

Here is my code for right now with default variable values.

```
public class GitActions
{
    public string url = "";
    public string RepoName = "test";
    public string path = @"C:\temp\rooted\test2";
    public string user = Properties.Settings.Default.User;
    public string pass = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
    public Signature sig = new Signature("test", "test", new DateTimeOffset(2011, 06, 16, 10, 58, 27, TimeSpan.FromHours(2)));

    public bool CloneRepo()
    {
        try
        {
            string clonedRepoPath = Repository.Clone(url, path, new CloneOptions()
            {
                CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
                {
                    Username = user,
                    Password = pass,
                }
            });
            Console.WriteLine("Clone Success");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clone Failure");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool PullRepo()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var repo = new Repository(path))
            {
                repo.Network.Pull(sig, new PullOptions()
                {
                    FetchOptions = new FetchOptions()
                    {
                        CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
                            {
                                Username = user,
                                Password = pass,
                            }
                    },
                    MergeOptions = new MergeOptions()
                });
                Console.WriteLine("Pull Success");
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pull Failure");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool SwitchBranch(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var repo = new Repository(path))
            {

                repo.Checkout(repo.Branches[name], sig);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Switch successful");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Branch Switch Failed");
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a `Pull()`, considering your scenario, I'd rather advise you to only perform a `Fetch()` which will only retrieve the updated content.

Given a repository, the following should take care of creating a new folder for each branch

```
var path = ... // Path where the repo has been cloned/fetched
var branchesRootPath = ...  // Target root directory where the new branches folder should be created
var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Ticks; // Unique number to always create new folders


using (var repo = new Repository(path))
{
    foreach (var b in repo.Branches)
    {
        // A branch name can contains a slash.
        var branchFolderName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", now, b.Name.Replace("/", "-"));
        var branchFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(
             Path.Combine(branchesRootPath, branchFolderName));

        // Force will ensure a clean checkout and update the working directory
        // with the content of the branch
        repo.Checkout(b, new CheckoutOptions
             { CheckoutModifiers = CheckoutModifiers.Force });

        // This body of this function is not described here, but should
        // recursively copy the working directory into the branchFolder directory
        //
        // Note: Everything should be copied *except* the ".git" directory
        CopyFilesRecursively(repo.Info.WorkingDirectory, branchFolder.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "now" variable supposed to be on the "branchFolderName" declaration?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I forgot to describe it. This is a unique number (the ticks) to prevent the overwriting of the previous version of folders.